# Consulta em 2 Tabelas Muito Lenta no mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT scanlators.* FROM lista_de_capitulos 
INNER JOIN scanlators ON JSON_CONTAINS(lista_de_capitulos.scanlator, scanlators.id) 
GROUP BY scanlators.url ORDER BY COUNT(lista_de_capitulos.id_manga) DESC LIMIT 100
```

Como posso melhorar velocidade de execução dessa consulta? está levando cerca de 15 segundos pra completar a execução atualmente.

Comment: Avalie o plano de execução e se, por acaso, a implementação de algum índice possa melhorar a performance de sua consulta.

Comment: esse json_contains parece custoso, não entendi pq está fazendo assim

Comment: @LucasMiranda e porque a coluna e um objeto.

Comment: mas precisa ser mesmo? ele vai olhar o objeto inteiro só pra ver se possui o id, isso não é nada performático, se você pudesse normalizar esse cara em outra tabela, você poderia indexar

Answer (score -1):

Ocorre que esta agrupando a tabela inteira, para depois selecionar as 100 primeiras linhas.
Teria que dizer que quer trabalhar na primeira centena de linhas.
Estou com mesmo problema e desconheço a solução

Comment: E como seria possível selecionar as 100 linhas com maior contagem sem contar todas elas antes?

Comment: acredito não ser possível associar somente 100 linhas, porque ele precisa avaliar mais de 50 mil linhas de capitulos e 500 de scan lator